# UNITY C# How do I edit value from script 1 in script 2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I recently tried to edit value from the first scrpt in the other, but it does not update at all. I know im doing something wrong but my google-fu is failing me yet again.

What im tryng to do is that object (Warrior) hits other object (Boss) it should substract boss's health by an amount of attack points in warrior script, it registers that it hit the boss, theres no errors, but the value of Boss health does not update.

Is it a nesting problem or inheritance? Maybe something else?

Also i should mention that "Warrior" has many instances that You can spawn.

Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WarriorHealthSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    // private int warriorHealth = 100;  - dont need it atm
    private int warriorAttack = 20;
    // public int warriorDefense = 10;   - dont need it atm
    private int warriorCooldown = 5;
    private int timeSinceLastAttack;

    public GameObject bossHealth;
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bossHealth = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Boss");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        HealthSystemScript healthSystemScript = bossHealth.GetComponent<HealthSystemScript>();
        //Check if warrior is touching Boss object
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Boss" && Time.time > warriorCooldown)
        {
            // Abort if we already attacked recently.
            if (Time.time - timeSinceLastAttack < warriorCooldown) return;
            { 
                //if collided object has "Boss" Tag then:
                if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Boss"))
                {
                    WarriorAttack(warriorAttack, healthSystemScript.currentHealth);
                    Debug.Log("took 20dmg!");



                    // Remember that we recently attacked.
                    timeSinceLastAttack = (int)Time.time;


                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void WarriorAttack(int damage, int bossHealth)
    {
        bossHealth -= damage;
    }
}
```

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify the health variable on the boss. It would be nice to see more code too, but from what I can see WarriorAttack needs to be modified to something like

```
 private void WarriorAttack(int damage, int bossHealth)
    {
        bossHealth.health -= damage;
        //or
        bossHealth.hit(damage);
    }
```

The `health` would be a public variable in this case on the `bossHealth` game object, or a `hit` a public function, depending on your setup.

Edit: I just noticed `healthSystemScript` on boss game object. I assume that script might hold the actual health, so instead of doing `bossHealth -= damage;` and separate function, maybe you need to modify the `healthSystemScript` variable directly. Not sure without more code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is about how the code is invoked. Let's talk about this line of code, where you pass 2 `Integer` values:

```
WarriorAttack(warriorAttack, healthSystemScript.currentHealth);
```

Modifying code a little we get an example where you can test what happens:

```
int hp = 30;

WarriorAttack(10, hp);

// what is the 'hp' value now?
//... yes, it will remain the same = 30.
```

This is called passing value-type variable (in this case `int`) as a value. This process is a bit harder to explain in few sentences, google this if description is not clear (look for keywords `C# pass variable by value vs pass by reference`: When you enter the method, C# will automatically create "copy" of that variable and insert the same int value, which was in the original variable. Now, you can work with this "copied" variable without issues, but if you modify it, it won't modify the "original" variable/value.

---

What you want to do instead, is just modify the object as:

```
WarriorAttack(warriorAttack, healthSystemScript);


private void WarriorAttack(int damage, HealthSystemScript objectThatWasHit)
{
    objectThatWasHit.currentHealth -= damage;
}
```

The difference is that the variable `healthSystemScript` is a "Reference-type" (class), which is passed to method as a reference. This way the C# will access the existing object directly, instead of making a copy.

Comment: The opposite of passing by value is passing by reference. One could declare the function as `WarriorAttack(int damage, ref int bossHealth)` which would pass the second parameter by reference so that any changes to it would appear in the referenced variable, e.g. `healthSystemScript.currentHealth`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another way of doing this.

Like other answers have said, passing `healthSystemScript.currentHealth` to your function like this

```
WarriorAttack(warriorAttack, healthSystemScript.currentHealth);
```

Creates a *copy* of the value, so your line `bossHealth -= damage;` is only modifying this copied value, not the original. This is because `int` is a value type, so is passed [by value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters), ie coppied.

A solution is to pass your whole script reference `healthSystemScript` which is a *reference* type so doing `healthSystemScript.currentHealth -= damage;` would correctly update the value. This is because classes are *reference types*.

If you want a simplified idea of how this works, imagine taking a copy of a reference to pass to a funciton. This copy will still be a valid reference to the same object as the original reference, so modifying the object through the "copy" of the reference will still modify the original object.

But better yet, your boss should be in charge of their own health. Add some function so boss can damage themselves like

```
healthSystemScript.TakeDamage(warriorAttack);
```

---

However, if you *really* want to modify the value like you are doing, it is possible to pass a *reference* to the *actual variable* inside your boss' `healthSystemScript`.

You would do it like so

```c#
private void WarriorAttack(int damage, ref int bossHealth)
{
    bossHealth -= damage;
}

WarriorAttack(warriorAttack, ref healthSystemScript.currentHealth);
```

This takes the value-type integer, usually passed by value (so copied) and passes it [by reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref), allowing the actual value to be modified.

However, I would still recommend just adding a `TakeDamage(int)` function to `healthSystemScript`. The above code is wierd and I wouldn't use it for this problem.